# Multiple interview dates offered. Should I choose one or let the company decide?

Tags: interviewing, email

I have been contacted for an interview. The company has proposed 2 different dates, and stated that they wait for my response to define the interview date.

If I am available on both the days, should I tell them so and let them decide, or should I choose one and confirm?

I know it may not have much impact on the overall hiring process, but what do the experienced guys here think about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Simple answer:** Just choose which one you prefer, and tell them!

They are offering you dates they have available.  They really don't care!  It's up to you.  If you are available both dates, then arbitrarily choose one.  It will honestly make no difference.  If you would rather get it out of the way, go for the earlier date.

*However*, in my experience, it's usually easier to be earlier in the process as the people on the interview panel often get a little "punch drunk" by the end of a good number of interviews.  But really, it is *entirely* up to you :)

Comment: This is a great answer. Another thing to keep in mind is for them, it's just another meeting on a calendar - what day/time it is matters not much at all. But for the interviewee it's a lot more meaningful as it normally involves more logistics, time off work, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Pick the day definitively and *perhaps* confirm it too. It probably has very little impact, but it never hurts to show them that you're decisive about things.

I also agree with the other answers that choosing the earlier date is a good idea.

Comment: +1 for decisiveness.  Someone who can't make a choice between two options given to them is not someone you want making decisions for your company.

Answer (score 2):

Some companies start screening you the moment they decide you're a worthy candidate. Be firm and call them the first opportunity you get (only use email if no other option is presented), thank them for inviting you and agree on a date as soon as possible. Unless this is an opportunity requiring very specific skillset, they'll most likely hire based on your character.

Also getting in as early as possible *might* be beneficial as you could become the standard against which they are comparing the other candidates instead of being one of the 'other candidates'.

Answer (score 2):

For tactical reasons, I would chose the first possible date. There is always the possibility that something goes wrong and either you or the interviewer are not available at the last minute. If that happens on the first possible date, there's a much better chance to arrange for a different date.

Answer (score 1):

If you are available on both the days, rather than pick one and (implicitly) reject the other, I suggest you respond with your preferred date as the 1st preference, and the other date as the 2nd preference. That way, it is less awkward for them to reschedule to the other date if they run into problems on the agreed date, while you don't lose anything.

A few years ago, I was asked to pick one of *three* dates for an interview (with those days being Monday, Thursday, and Friday). I picked the Monday, only to hear from them couple of days later, that Monday is "not possible", and I should pick either Thursday or Friday. I picked Thursday, and the next day, they called again to inform Thursday is also "not possible" and hence, interview is scheduled on Friday!

I was bemused by what I perceived as silliness at the time, and wondered why they even bothered giving me options in the first place. Later, with more experience, I could see it from their perspective, and could imagine how awkward they must have felt to make those calls. Listing those dates in the order of my preference would have made it less awkward for them.